# How to combine MySQL number of rows of the joined table, including 0?

Tags: mysql, join, count, null

I have two tables: 'company' and 'order'. The first one contains company info and the second one holds all orders made with a company. (`order`.`company` = `company`.`ID`).

I am making a query on the first table, for example all companies in the city of New York. I would like to make a join with the `order` table, so that it immediately shows how many orders for a company was made. I could do this with a simple JOIN query, however, it does not include 0. For example, if a company has no orders yet, it will not show up at all, while it should be in the list with 0 orders.

Desired end result:

```
----------------------------------------
|  ID  |     Name    |   ...  | Orders |
----------------------------------------
| 105  |  Company A  |   ...  |   14   |
| 115  |  Company B  |   ...  |    5   |
| 120  |  Company C  |   ...  |    0   |
| 121  |  Company D  |   ...  |    0   |
----------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your table structure please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `left join` with aggregation:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, count(o.company) as total
FROM companies c left outer join
     orders o
     on c.id = o.company
WHERE c.city = 'New York'
GROUP BY c.ID;
```

In MySQL, it is best to avoid subqueries in the `from` clause -- where possible -- because the derived table is actually created.

The `COUNT()` expression is counting the number of matches by counting the number of non-null values in the id field used for the join.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT com.id,com.name,od.orders FROM compnay AS com 
LEFT JOIN orders AS od ON od.company = com.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Indra, but I don't have a number of orders to directly select from. That is why it needs to be calculated on the fly. The question has been answered though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT companies.ID,companies.Name ,orders.total FROM
(SELECT ID,Name FROM company where county ='NEW YORK')  companies
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company,COUNT(*) as total FROM order GROUP BY company) orders
ON orders.company = companies.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, this answer does seem to work. However, Gordon's answer doesn't consist of any subqueries, which makes his answer the best answer. Thanks again.